# Need a Fancy Loop in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first post here, although I have used this site for many years to help me find snippets of code to achieve the results I needed. So, if I haven't posted this correctly, forgive me in advance...

I have an iframe on my page that loads the first of a set of images from ancestry.com:

```
    <div id="ancestryiframeholder">
    <div class="well padding larger" align="center">Some Districts, like in cities and towns have more than one Sub-district included in the table. The program only automatically loads the first Sub-district from the set.<br />You will have to use Ancestry's menu below this message to choose the subsequent Sub-district(s). See the Sub-district list for more information.
    <iframe id="iframe" class="" src="http://interactive.ancestry.com/8991/1921_041-E002904764/8517860#?imageId=1921_043-e002907748" style="height:300px; width:100%;"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I also have a group of links in a list that varies in length from one page to the other, based upon the place names for that particular page.

```
    <ul><br /><br />
    <li><a id="fergusonscove" href="/census/novascotia/test/fergusonscove.html" rel="#iframe">Ferguson's Cove</a></li>
    <li><a id="herringcove" href="/census/novascotia/test/herringcove.html" rel="#iframe">Herring Cove</a></li>
    <li><a id="portugeusecove" href="/census/novascotia/test/portugeusecove.html" rel="#iframe">Portugeuse Cove</a></li>
    </ul>
```

This list can be long, depending on how many places there are. When user clicks one of these links, two things happen. A document from my server is loaded into a div with the rel iframe. And, a new image from Ancestry is loaded into the previous iframe I mentioned above with the id iframe. I am making this happen by using the script from here - http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/index.htm - to accomplish the loading of the document into the iframe. I am then using the code below to load the new image from Ancestry into the other iframe. All works as expected. The new image loads into the iframe without the need for a page refresh.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var addEvent = (function(){return window.addEventListener? function(el, ev, f){
        el.addEventListener(ev, f, false);
    }:window.attachEvent? function(el, ev, f){
        el.attachEvent('on' + ev, f);
    }:function(){return;};
})();
var removeEvent = (function(){return window.addEventListener? function(el, ev, f){
        el.removeEventListener(ev, f, false);
    }:window.attachEvent? function(el, ev, f){
        el.detachEvent('on' + ev, f);
    }:function(){return;};
})();

    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'),
        fergusonscove = document.getElementById('fergusonscove');
        herringcove = document.getElementById('herringcove');
        portugeusecove = document.getElementById('portugeusecove');
        halifaxward01 = document.getElementById('halifaxward01');


    function changeframe(){
        var iDoc = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument || null);
    removeEvent(iframe, 'load', changeframe);
    }
    addEvent(fergusonscove, 'click', function () {
        addEvent(iframe, 'load', changeframe);
        iframe.src = 'http://interactive.ancestry.com/8991/1921_041-E002904764/8517860#?imageId=1921_043-e002907748';
        });

        addEvent(herringcove, 'click', function () {
        addEvent(iframe, 'load', changeframe);
        iframe.src = 'http://interactive.ancestry.com/8991/1921_041-E002904764/8517860#?imageId=1921_043-e002907755';
    });

    addEvent(portugeusecove, 'click', function () {
        addEvent(iframe, 'load', changeframe);
        iframe.src = 'http://interactive.ancestry.com/8991/1921_041-E002904764/8517860#?imageId=1921_043-e002907762';
    });

        addEvent(halifaxward01, 'click', function () {
        addEvent(iframe, 'load', changeframe);
        iframe.src = 'http://interactive.ancestry.com/8991/1921_041-E002904764/8517860#?imageId=1921_043-e002908373';
    });

}); 
</script>
```

As you can see, I am doing everything manually for this part. As it stands now, I will have to type all of this by hand for each place name. And there will be thousands of them.

```
     var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'),
        fergusonscove = document.getElementById('fergusonscove');
        herringcove = document.getElementById('herringcove');
        portugeusecove = document.getElementById('portugeusecove');
        halifaxward01 = document.getElementById('halifaxward01');
```

Etc. Etc.
Then, to get the new Ancestry image, I again have to type by hand for each place.

```
    function changeframe(){
        var iDoc = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument || null);
    removeEvent(iframe, 'load', changeframe);
    }
    addEvent(fergusonscove, 'click', function () {
        addEvent(iframe, 'load', changeframe);
        iframe.src = 'http://interactive.ancestry.com/8991/1921_041-E002904764/8517860#?imageId=1921_043-e002907748';
        });

        addEvent(herringcove, 'click', function () {
        addEvent(iframe, 'load', changeframe);
        iframe.src = 'http://interactive.ancestry.com/8991/1921_041-E002904764/8517860#?imageId=1921_043-e002907755';
    });
```

Etc. Etc.
Is there a way to automate this somewhat to cut down on the manual labour?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For variables, you just need to `$('a').click(function(){
  var myVar = $(this).attr("id);
})` , then you just do an if else for the value of myVar when you addEvent.

Comment: I can see that working, but what about the differences with the Ancestry URL's?

Comment: @Cyval - Is there a quotation mark missing in your code at the end of ("id)?

Comment: Oh my bad. Sorry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need a `for` loop.

You should combine the code for one item together in one function that you then give parameters.

The trick is to take two of those examples and look for what is different in each of them. Each thing that changes needs a parameter.

Let's look at a simple example:

```
var users = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'];
console.log('Hello, %s!', users[0]);
console.log('Hello, %s!', users[1]);
console.log('Hello, %s!', users[2]);
```

This will print:

> Hello, Alice!
>
> Hello, Bob!
>
> Hello, Charlie!

... but we had to write three console.log statements. No fun if there are thousands of users. Let's try to make this code more generic. First, we make a function:

```
function greet() {
    console.log('Hello, %s!', users[0]);
}
```

We're halfway there, but this will always print the greeting for Alice, as the `users[0]` part is hardcoded. This is the part we need to replace by a parameter:

```
function greet(name) {
    console.log('Hello, %s!', name);
}
```

Now, we can simply loop over our users to greet all of them, no matter how many there are:

```
for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
    greet(users[i]);
}
```

I know this isn't a copy-paste answer, but if you apply these principles and some patience you should be able to pull this off.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My OCD is my downfall ... must stay away from overflow!. This would be a much cleaner way to handle the your requirements. In JS the `ancestoryService()` is the init fn. Addition additional object service properties is easy.

**NOTES:**

1. I'm using lodash JS library which is must have for JS dev!
2. I use Angular JS which is great for JS OOP. Has a steep learning
   curve but makes for great code. React is also brilliant.
3. btw for DOM parsing take a look at JS DOM element API. I use that
   extensively. Example, you could build a observer service that will
   watch the ancestors DOM to automatically update. You can also add /
   extract meaningful DOM info.

*Working Sandbox*

https://jsfiddle.net/nb3gmdkL/

**HTML EXAMPLE**

```
    <body>
      <h1>Ancetory</h1>
      <div id="Bob" src="http://www.bob.com"></div>
      <div id="Jack" src="http://www.jack.com"></div>
      <div id="Fred" src="http://www.fred.com"></div>
      <div id="Kate"src="http://www.kate.com"></div>
      <div id="Bob"src="http://www.bob.com"></div>
    </body>
```

**CODE**

```
 (function() {

    function ImageService() {
      var model = this,
      item = {};

      model.setInstance = function(instance) {
         item['id'] = instance['id'] ? instance['id'] : null;
         item['url'] = instance.getAttribute("src") ? instance.getAttribute("src") : null;
      }

      model.getInstance = function(instance) {
         return item;
      }

      model.getId = function() {
         return item['id'];
      }

        model.getUrl = function() {
         return item['url'];
      }

      return {
        setInstance: function(instance) {
          model.setInstance(instance);
        },
        getInstance: function() {
          return model.getInstance();
        },
        getId: function() {
          return model.getInstance();
        },
      }
    }

    function ImageCollection() {
      var collection = this,
          store = [];

      collection.add = function(instance) {
                if (instance) {
             store.push(instance);
            } else {
            console.log('Oops, conatins', instance)
          }
      }

      collection.contains = function(instance) {
        if (store) {
          return undefined !== _.find(store, function(item, k) {
            return item.getId() == instance.getId();
          });
        }
      }

      collection.all = function() {
         return store;
      }

            return {
            add: function(instance) {
             collection.add(instance);
          },
          all: function() {
             return collection.all();
          }
        }
    }

    function ancestoryService() {
      var allElements =document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
      console.log(allElements);

      if (allElements) {
        var collection = new ImageCollection();

        _.each(allElements, function(item, key) {
          var instance = new ImageService();
          instance.setsetInstance(instance);
          console.log('get instance', instance.getId());
          console.log('get instance', instance.getUrl());
          console.log('collection add', collection.add(instance));
          console.log('collection all', collection.all());
        })
      }
    }

    ancestoryService();
    })();
```